# Selenium code stop working after upgrade - 'Cannot start the driver service - C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

I am facing regression after upgrading selenium from 3.141 to 4.0 to following code:

```
var driverService2 = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(path);
        driverService2.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver(driverService2, new FirefoxOptions());
        string Target = "https://www.linkedin.com/";
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Target);
```

I am getting following error
**OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:20548/'**

I am using selenium using following nugget:

[Visula Studio Nugget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRC5t.jpg)

My using latest GekoDriver.exe downloaded from  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
geckodriver-v0.30.0-win64.zip

If I reverse back to last version of Selenium, code works fine.  Is there any know solution available.

Thank you for your guidance

Comment: Just a quick guess.. There is no constructor for service and options. https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriver.htm . 3rd argument TimeSpan is required based on this doc.

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? You need to use the correct FirefoxDriver that corresponds with your Firefox browser version.

Comment: @MaxDaroshchanka  This code works with last version of selenium 3.141 and stop working with 4.0. However based on you advise I change the constructor calling but still the exception on Selenium 4.0 .

Comment: @GregBurghardt I am using 97.0  64 bit  . Is there any simple way to know which version of firefox is supported by 4.0

Comment: Hm. It is surprisingly difficult to find out which Firefox versions go with the driver versions.

Comment: @GregBurghardt   - Yes               https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/upgrade_to_selenium_4/

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Where do I find link browser verion

Comment: Do you have a firewall running or maybe anti-virus software which might be interfering?

Comment: @GregBurghardt  No . No firewall . I have version of code with Selenium 3.141 on my laptop and that works very well. If i use with 4.0 we have issue. Do we have any alternative to selenium

Comment: Not that this is an answer, but what happens when you switch to ChromeDriver? Just curious if this is a Selenium issue or web driver issue.